# Как удалить из списка элементы с одинаковым значением поля?

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть класс

```
public class File {

            private String format;
        }
//создаю список и помещаю в него объекты
List<File> filesFrom = new ArrayList<>();
        filesFrom.add(file1);
        filesFrom.add(file2);
        filesFrom.add(file3);
        filesFrom.add(file4);
        filesFrom.add(file5);
```

Значение поля `format` у некоторых объектов совпадает. К примеру: `file1 - "txt"`, `file2 - "txt"`, `file3 - "doc"`, `file4 - "jpg"`, `file5 - "txt"`
Мне надо удалить объекты у которых значение поля дублируется, чтобы в итоге осталось только объекты с различными форматами. То есть должны остаться в списке объекты `file1`, `file3`, `file4`

Я пытаюсь делать следующим образом

```
for (int i = filesFrom.size() - 1; i > -1 ; i--) {
        if (filesFrom.get(0).getFormat().equals(filesFrom.get(i).getFormat())){
            filesFrom.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Получается, что удаляются все файлы c начала и с конца списка, а остаются только файлы с форматами `doc` и `jpg`.
 Подскажите как добиться требуемого мне результата.

И наверное через `iterator`будет правильней делать ? Но не пойму как (((

Comment: если делать руками, то вам нужно два цикла. Первый будет перебирать все элементы в списке с начала, второй будет проходить хвост списка до текущего элемента и удалять похожие на текущий. Если учить плохому, то `Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>(); filesFrom.removeIf( f -> !seen.add( f.format ) );`

Comment: zRrr, я сделал почти так, создал новый `Set<String> strings = new TreeSet<>();` , прошёл циклом по `filesFrom`, взял геттером формат и положил в `strings` , таким образом остались форматы без дублирования

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переопределите методы equals и hashCode, используйте set вместо List и будет Вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант-залипуха с Map. Вариант с  equals и hashCode лучше. Этого варианта плюс только в том, что не перетираются значения по ключу, а остаются первые добавленные

```
    Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.putIfAbsent(file1.getFormat(), file1);
    map.putIfAbsent(file2.getFormat(), file2);
    map.putIfAbsent(file3.getFormat(), file3);
    map.putIfAbsent(file4.getFormat(), file4);
    map.putIfAbsent(file5.getFormat(), file5);

    Collection<File> values = map.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно без переопределения `equals(), hashCode()`, нужен только геттер для `private String format;`

```
    Set<Format> list = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Format::getFormat));
    list.add(new Format("txt"));
    list.add(new Format("txt"));
    list.add(new Format("jpg"));
    list.add(new Format("rar"));
    list.add(new Format("jpg"));

    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```